# Is there any relation between Virtual destructor and Vtable

Tags: c++, virtual, vtable

If we write virtual function it adds a vtable in object of that class. Is it true for virtual destructor too ? Is vtable used to implement virtualness of destructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Some information is needed to allow the right destructor to be called when the object is deleted via a base class pointer.  Whether that information is a small integer index or a pointer doesn't matter (although dynamic linkage probably implies that it's a pointer).  Naturally, that information needs to be adjacent to (inside) the pointed-to object.

Adding a virtual method of any kind, including a destructor, to a class that had none before, will increase sizeof(class).

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that the C++ standard requires any particular mechanism for producing the correct behavior, but yes, that's a typical implementation. A class with at least 1 virtual function has a table of (virtual) function pointers, the destructor being one of them, if it's marked virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.  Sorry I don't have a definitive reference to back up my assertion.  But how else would you get different behavior when using just a pointer to the object?

Comment: There are other mechanisms to implement virtual methods. vtables are just the most common (and easy to implement).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Virtual destructor is like any other virtual method. Vtable entry will get added.

Answer (score 0):

It is treated like any other normal function and will be added to the vtable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://geneura.ugr.es/~jmerelo/c++-faq/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.5